# POST Rest call with attached file in java

Tags: java, rest

```
public static InputStream postCallMultipart(String api, String requestBody,
     List<NameValuePair> uploadList) {
  URL url = null;
  InputStream isResponse = null;
  HttpURLConnection httpCon = null;
  OutputStream output = null;
  String charset = "UTF-8";

  MultipartEntity reqEntity =
        new MultipartEntity(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
  lastCallResponseCode = -1;
  try {

     for (NameValuePair fileUpload : uploadList) {
        String fileName = fileUpload.getName();
        File fileHandler = new File(fileUpload.getValue());
        System.out.println(fileUpload.getValue()+"============"+fileName);
        FileBody fileBody = new FileBody(fileHandler);
        reqEntity.addPart(fileName, fileBody);
     }

     if (null != requestBody && !requestBody.isEmpty()) {
        reqEntity.addPart("rawData", new StringBody(requestBody));
     }

     url = new URL(serverUrl + api);
     Reporter.log("POST: " + url.toString(), true);

     httpCon = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
     httpCon.setUseCaches(false);
     httpCon.setDoInput(true);
     httpCon.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
     httpCon.setRequestMethod("POST");
     httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept",contentType);
     httpCon.setRequestProperty("Accept-Charset", charset);
     httpCon.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data");
     httpCon.addRequestProperty("Content-length",
           reqEntity.getContentLength() + "");
     httpCon.addRequestProperty(reqEntity.getContentType().getName(),
           reqEntity.getContentType().getValue());
     httpCon.setRequestProperty("Authorization", HTTP_BASIC_AUTH
           + SINGLE_SPACE + LOCAL_SUPERADMIN_CREDENTIAL_BASE64);
     if(requestHeaders != null){
          for(Entry<String, String> header : requestHeaders.entrySet()){
              httpCon.setRequestProperty(header.getKey(), header.getValue());
          }
     }

     output = httpCon.getOutputStream();
     reqEntity.writeTo(output);
     output.close();
     httpCon.connect();

     lastCallResponseCode = httpCon.getResponseCode();
     isResponse = httpCon.getInputStream();
  } catch (IOException e) {
     isResponse = httpCon.getErrorStream();
     Reporter.log("REST call unsuccessful: " + e.getMessage(), true);
  }
  return isResponse;
```

}

I am using the above method to upload a file(.pak) using rest call. Any mistake I am doing here? Using the rest client tool for crome browser, I am able to do. I am just putting POST request with file attached and the name of the field to which I attached file is "contents".

Comment: It is throwing 500 error and when I remove using any "Content-Type" throwing 406 error.

Comment: Check the server side logs(if they are available to you).

Comment: I am able to make the call with browser rest client tool.

Comment: Is there anything else other than 500 error ?

Comment: You need to look in the server log to understand the 500, or to have someone look for you and tell you the relevant bit (depending on admin policy). It can also help if you see whether you're getting an entity back on error; the server might be configured to give you more info. (That's more likely with a 4?? than a 5?? but it's worth a try.)

Answer (score 0):

According to your comment you should sniff the content between client and server for working rest client and not-working java code. You should see some different stuff like missing header or something similar. Server can contain various business logic and can refuse your request for millions reasons.